# mapping from LowerUnderscore to PascalCase

Tags: automapper

I have set up a `MapperConfiguration` with a source `SourceMemberNamingConvention` of *LowerUndercore* and a destination `DestinationMemberNamingConvention` of *Pascal*.

This is working except on the following types of properties that have numbers in the name.

**Source entity column names**

```
column_1_name
column_2_name
```

**Destination DTO property names**

```
Column1Name
Column2Name
```

Should this be able to map correctly, or is there another configuration property I need to set?

Comment: You'll need to write your own regular expression that does that.